# Good practices using forms

Tags: symfony

I have to change a web that is using different types to generate forms. There is in Bundle/Form/ folder 2 files:

- ProductType.php
- ProductEditType.php

It's working fine, the first one is used to generate the new product form and the second one the form to edit it.

Almost 95% of both files is the same, so I guess it has to exist any way to use one type to generate more than one form.

I have been reading about how to modify forms using form events, but I have not found clearly what is the general good practice about it.

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

I wrote an Event Subscriber as follows.

```
<?php
namespace Project\MyBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Description of ProductTypeOptionsSubscriber
 *
 * @author Javi
 */
class ProductTypeOptionsSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
}

public function preSetData(FormEvent $event){

    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if( !$data || !$data->getId() ){
        // No ID, it's a new product
        //.... some code for other options .....
        $form->add('submit','submit',
            array(
                'label' => 'New Produtc',
                'attr'  => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')
                ));
    }else{
        // ID exists, generating edit options .....
        $form->add('submit','submit',
            array(
                'label' => 'Update Product',
                'attr'  => array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')
                ));
    }

}
}
```

In ProductType, inside buildForm:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new ProductTypeOptionsSubscriber());
```

So that's all, it was very easy to write and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read this cookbook [event subscriber](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data), the first scenario can do for you.

Returning to the example of the documentation..

Add the fields that you want them to being modified in this way:

```
$builder->addEventSubscriber(new AddNameFieldSubscriber());
```

Then create the event event subscriber by entering your logic:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Form/EventListener/AddNameFieldSubscriber.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Form\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class AddNameFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_set_data
        // event and that the preSetData method should be called.
        return array(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData');
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        // check if the product object is "new"
        // If you didn't pass any data to the form, the data is "null".
        // This should be considered a new "Product"
        if (!$data || !$data->getId()) {
            $form->add('name', 'text');
            ....
            ..... // other fields
        }
    }
}
```